# The OutputPath property is not set for this project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I try to compile my project from x86 debug mode in Visual Studio 2008. I am getting this error. When I looked at the property group of the project that complained, I see output path is set.

Here is the property group section for that .csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  <BaseAddress>285212672</BaseAddress>
  <FileAlignment>4096</FileAlignment>
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
 <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
```

Can any one shed the light on this?

NOTE: When I compiled this Debug and Any CPU it worked.

**UPDATED:** Error 1   The OutputPath property is not set for this project.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid Configuration/Platform combination.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform='x86'

Comment: Ok and what configuration and platform do you use? Debug + x86 or something else?

Comment: Yes VS configuration manager I choose debug + x86

Comment: @DmitryShkuropatsky updated error message

Comment: It looks correct. Is there another project in the solution that may cause the error?

Comment: @DmitryShkuropatsky you are right it was another project that had issue. But VS complained about the project that is being compiled

Comment: over 8 years and Microsoft still hasn't fixed this...

Comment: sharpdevelop 5  has this issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error shown in visual studio for the project (Let's say A) does not have issues. When I looked at the output window for the build line by line for each project, I saw that it was complaining about another project (B) that had been referred as assembly in project A. Project B added into the solution. But it had not been referred in the project A  as project reference instead as assembly reference from different location. That location contains the assembly which compiled for Platform AnyCpu. Then I removed the assembly reference from the project A and added project B as a reference. It started compiling. 
Not sure though how this fix worked.

Comment: Deffo try it with \p:Platform="AnyCPU" instead of \p:Platform="Any CPU". That worked form me! Was looking at this for ages!

Comment: AnyCPU (Without the space) also worked for me. Thanks Lee.

Comment: I encountered the error while running a build process on TFS 2017, after I changed the "Path to solution or packages.config" from a .sln to a .vbproj.  Changing BuildPlatform to AnyCPU worked for me too.  See the note under "Platform" here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/visual-studio-build

Comment: In my case, when launching the build from TFS, `"any cpu"` was the default value for BuildPlatform. Changing to `"AnyCPU"` solved the problem.

Comment: This is 2020 - AnyCPU vs Any CPU is still a trouble maker. I'm using VS2019 and still get this on new projects.
MS why are you punishing the developer community?

Comment: @XouDo how did you figure this out, and what's the difference between both? It solved my problem btw.

Comment: @Zeeshan I checked many things in the TFS build and the csproj, since the error message is clearly related to `configuration` and `platform`. `AnyCPU` vs `any cpu` : the case is different, and there's an extra space in the middle. As for the reason why, maybe the default configuration name changed along versions of Visual Studio/TFS...?

Answer (score 263):

I had exact same error after adding a new configuration via ConfigurationManager in Visual Studio.

It turned out when the 'Production' configuration was added for the whole solution (and each project) the OutputPath element **was not** added to the .csproj files.

To fix, I went to the Build tab in project properties, changed OutputPath from `\bin\Production\` to `\bin\Production` (deleted trailing `\`) and saved changes. This forced creation of the OutputPath element in the .csproj file and the project has built successfully.

Sounds like a glitch to me.

Comment: Nice catch on this mercurial error. Would never have guessed that a single slash could make that big of a difference. Have a Good Answer badge.

Comment: In my case, building a proj file, the difference between `any cpu`and `anycpu` was the issue, but your post helped me see that.

Comment: Thank you Roman you saved my day...if only i could upvote your answer 100 times! :)

Comment: Just encountered this in VS 2017 v15.6.6, bacon saved, thanks!

Comment: @Joshua Drake, this is an important issue when using VSTS. Visual studio online uses 'any cpu', while local visual studio uses 'anycpy'. Important for build scripts.

Comment: This was exactly my issue. What a great answer! we should contact the MS devs on India about this! it screams "patch!".

Comment: It's incredible that this fixes the problem.  Sometimes I wonder about the usability of VS beyond "Hello World!" apps!

Comment: same issue.. strange. Seems like a glitch

Comment: same with VS 2015, while trying cefsharp

Comment: I had the same issue with VS2019 as of 17-May-2022. What I had to do was that I had to manually edit the affected project's csproj file and deleted the trailing \. Reloaded the solution and that worked. Nothing I did while in the VS IDE worked.

Comment: The same problem and solution in VS 2022 (17.4.2)

Answer (score 32):

If you are using WiX look at this (there is a bug)
http://www.cnblogs.com/xixifusigao/archive/2012/03/20/2407651.html

Sometimes new build configurations get added to the `.wixproj` file further down the file, that is, separated from their sibling config definitions by other unrelated XML elements.

Simply edit the `.wixproj` file so that all the `<PropertyGroup>` sections that define your build configs are adjacent to one another. (To edit the `.wixproj` in VS2013 right click on project in Solution Explorer, Unload project, right-click again->Edit YourProject.wixproj. Reload after editing the file.)

Comment: thanks, this fixed it for me. I had a lot of weird behaviour the more configurations I added to the project. As soon as I cleaned up the project file everything worked fine. (This bug was first reported in 2012? great...)

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it for me as well

Answer (score 29):

You can see this error in VS 2008 if you have a project in your solution that references an assembly that cannot be found.  This could happen if the assembly comes from another project that is not part of your solution but should be.  In this case simply adding the correct project to the solution will solve it.

Check the References section of each project in your solution. If any of them has a reference with an red x next to it, then it you have found your problem. That assembly reference cannot be found by the solution.

The error message is a bit confusing but I've seen this many times.

Comment: In my case it was a "yellow warning"

Answer (score 22):

This happened to me because I had moved the following line close to the beginning of the .csproj file:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets"/>
```

It needs to be placed after the PropertyGroups that define your Configuration|Platform.

Comment: I just exported a bunch of DLL/EXE using .NET Reflector and it generated the .CSPROJ wrong like you described.  Wow never seen this one before.

Answer (score 15):

had this problem as output from Azure DevOps after setting to build the .csproj instead of the .sln in the Build Pipeline.

The solution for me:
Edit .csproj of the affected project, then copy your whole

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCpu' ">
```

Node, paste it, and then change the first line as followed:

```
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|any cpu' ">
```

The reason is, that in my case the error said

```
Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='release'  Platform='any cpu'.
```

Why Azure wants to use "any cpu" instead of the default "AnyCpu" is a mystery for me, but this hack works.

Comment: By following your idea I found out that in my case I didn't needed to make changes in the project, but instead in my Visual Studio Build step in DevOps I set up Confguration field to use variable with the AnyCpu value.

Comment: @donatasj87 would you mind posting the full value of this field please?

Comment: Full value is exactly the same, this also should work in TFS build. It just needs to match the value that is set up in your .csproj file. You can see it in this picture: https://pasteboard.co/JbdvBT5.png

Comment: You may also need to add a property group for ``Release|x86``

Answer (score 9):

I encountered the same error but the problem turned out to be because I had created a new configuration in my solution that didn't exist in referenced assemblies from another solution.

This can be resolved by opening the related solution and adding the new configuration to it as well.

This post gave me the idea to check the referenced assemblies after I'd already confirmed that all projects within my solution had the correct configuration:

http://gabrielmagana.com/2010/04/solution-to-the-outputpath-property-is-not-set-for-this-project/

Answer (score 5):

If you get this error only when you try to compile your project from commandline using MSBuild (like in my case) then the solution is to passing the outputpath manually to MSBuild with an argument like `/p:OutputPath=MyFolder`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error, so I looked on project settings and there in "Build" section is "Build output path" option. And value was empty. So I filled in "bin\" value a error disappeared. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

I have:

1. **Right-click on project** with issue -> **Unload Project**
2. **Right-click on project** and choose **Edit *.csproj**
3. Copy-paste
   the configuration from existing configuration which works with specific name and targeting platform (I had **Release |
   x64**):

   ```
   <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
     <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
     <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
     <Optimize>true</Optimize>
     <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
     <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
     <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
     <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
     <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
4. **Right-click project** -> **Reload Project**
5. **Rebuild** project/solution

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after I have added new configurations and deleted the "debug" and "release" configs.
In my case I was using a cmd file to run the build and publish process, but the same error was thrown.
**The solution for me:**
In the csproj file the following:

```
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug< /Configuration>
```

was setting the Configuration to "Debug" if I did not specify an explicit one. After changing the node value from "debug" to my custom configuration, it all worked smoothly. Hope this will also help whoever is reading this :)

Comment: Details for this solution are mentioned in this forum post.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/87b8aba4-9c61-4cfa-88f3-6236ee813582/msbuild-package-fails-with-outputpath-property-is-not-set-error?forum=msbuild

Answer (score 2):

Another crazy possibility:
If you follow a simple source control arrangement of putting Branch\Main, Main, and Release next to each other and you somehow end up adding an existing project from Main instead of Branch\Main (assuming your working solution is Branch\Main), you may see this error.

The solution is simple: reference the right project!

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem when adding a project to a solution then referencing it from yet another project in the same solution-- got the yellow warning icon over the reference, notice that path was empty.

The solution was similar to what @Amzath suggested, my projects were being compiled with different Target Frameworks, eg. .NET 4.0 vs 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the built address of my app was set to another computer that was turned off so i turned it on and restart VS and problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Another cause: you add a project reference from project A to project B in solution X. However, solution Y that already contains project A is now broken, until you also add project B to solution Y.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem,
Just edit the .wixproj to have all of the 
`<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' ... >` elements to be side by side.

That solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

The WiX project I was using was hard-set in the configuration manager for `x64` across the board. When making the Custom Action project for the solution, it defaulted everything to `x86` within the `.csproj` file. So I unloaded the project, edited it by changing all `x86` to `x64`, saved, reloaded, and was good to go after that.

I don't understand why I had to do this. The configuration manager was set to build as x64, but just wouldn't get set in the `csproj` file :(

Answer (score 1):

For me, the error wasn't caused by an obscure issue as seems to have been the case for others e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31703751/5134722). In my case, the error message was pretty spot on at describing what was wrong. It was saying that I was attempting to build for a specific build configuration & target platform, but I didn't have that combination of configuration/platform defined in my project properties file. So I explored two options:

1. Modify the project file to support the given target platform, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57147788/5134722)
2. Modify the target platform of the build to one of the existing supported configurations as per the project properties

Both worked in the sense that both made the issue go away. But the second one was the correct one for me. The problem I had was as follows:

1. In VS, I had a target platform of x86 and there was a PropertyGroup for this in the project file, so this was all working fine.
2. But when I tried to build from the command line, using `MSBuild.exe` the default target platform was "any cpu", unless explicitly specified as a command line argument.

So the fix in my case, since I wanted to target x86, was to explicitly tell MSBuild on the command line to build for the x86 platform, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10511759/5134722).

To quote that answer:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe my.sln /t:build /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x86
```

Notice the important part:

```
;Platform=x86
```

Comment: I would believe that you encounter the same issue that I did and write about below https://stackoverflow.com/a/78004581/7984 where the issue was in the .sln and not the .csproj

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the other suggestions posted here, I discovered the solution for me was to remove the following section from the `.csproj` file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Service Include="{808359B6-6B82-4DF5-91FF-3FCBEEBAD811}" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Apparently this service from the original project (unavailable on local machine) was halting the entire build process, even though it wasn't essential for compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem after adding a new platform to my project. In my case .csproj file was under Perforce source control and was read-only. I checked it out but VS didn't catch the change until I restarted it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issue on a Xamarin Project. It is maybe rare case but in case anyone else is having the issue. my project structure was like below

- xamarin.Android project had a reference from xamarin.android.library project.
- I created a plugin using some code from android.library project.
- Now here is the problem. if you add project reference or nuget installation on xamarin.android library project. You will get this error. Developers assume that code was inside Android.Library project and i must reference the new plugin on this project. NO!
- you must add a reference on Main Android project. because plugin->library->main project output isnt produced.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Philip Atz, I had the following line at the top of my .csproj file.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" />
```

Moving it further down solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of different answers to this question AND and my solution was different that any other that I have read so far, so here is how I fixed this for posterity, in the hopes it may help someone else.

1. My problem started after I had added "x64" configurations in my .csproj **AND removed** all "Any CPU" configurations from my .csproj.
2. For some obscure reason the VS2022 "Configuration Manager" **did not update properly** the solution file (.sln).

   - Configuration Manager in VS2022 WAS showing my project as using x64,
   - However, in the .sln it still looked like this:

```
{8B3B7A08-397D-4CA9-9823-A5CCADCF80A1}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
{8B3B7A08-397D-4CA9-9823-A5CCADCF80A1}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
{8B3B7A08-397D-4CA9-9823-A5CCADCF80A1}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
{8B3B7A08-397D-4CA9-9823-A5CCADCF80A1}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
```

3. And therefore, when MSBuild was building using the .sln, it was trying to  build the "Any CPU" configuration of my .csproj, although it **no longer** existed in the .csproj
4. I simply fixed my .sln as such and the problem was solved:

```
{8B3B7A08-397D-4CA9-9823-A5CCADCF80A1}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
{8B3B7A08-397D-4CA9-9823-A5CCADCF80A1}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|x64
{8B3B7A08-397D-4CA9-9823-A5CCADCF80A1}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
{8B3B7A08-397D-4CA9-9823-A5CCADCF80A1}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|x64
```

**IMPORTANT side note**:

- By removing the "Any CPU" configurations from my .csproj, the **default values** for the `Platform` property **was no longer correct** in the .csproj

  - It was showing as such below, even though there were no such AnyCPU platform defined in this one .csproj

```
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
```

- Had it been set to a valid platform, I would assume that MSBuild would have **falled back on using it**, even though the .sln was not telling the right story.

  - Which in turn would have hidden the underlying .sln issue
  - Which is why I believe other answers that indicate to change the .csproj to set the default Platform condition DO work with a .csproj fix:

```
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x64</Platform>
```

- However, a fix that relies on a default .csproj value, as opposed to using the desired build configuration instructions from .sln could cause **other grievances** down the line.