# Azure Functions C# Precompiled Local Publish Error OutputPath Not Set

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I am writing a C# Pre-compiled Azure Function Project in Visual Studio 2017. Before abstracting the POCOs into a separate class library I was able to publish to Azure. (The benefit was separation of the business logic and objects from the Azure Functions allowing me to test each unit.)

When debugging locally I receive no errors. The error is when I click "Publish" on my Azure Functions project and the deploy script starts. The error received in the Output window immediately after "Publish Started":

> {VSPath}\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(750,5): error : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'Loans.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Release'  Platform='Any CPU'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [{Path}\Loans.csproj]

A Copy of the csproj files Containing the respective OutputPath's and configurations exists on my [GitHub](http://github.com/justinkneff/AzureFunctions-LoanApplications).

I have Visual Studio 2017 15.5.3, .NET 4.6.1, extension for Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools 15.0.31106.0

How can I publish to Azure Functions while abstracting my business logic away?

Comment: I just cloned your project and I can publish to a folder without any errors.

Comment: i see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086795/the-outputpath-property-is-not-set-for-this-project?rq=1) in "Related" seems like quite similar ')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my extension for Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools from 15.0.31106.0 to 15.0.40108.0 and I can now publish.

Like comments suggested I tried setting the OutputPath property manually but that didn't fix it. I tried changing the other property values as well to no avail. Reinstalling/Updating the Azure Development Workload probably would have solved it as well as that would have been latest.

Comment: This worked for me.  My output path was already correctly set, as well. Applying the updates from within Visual Studio 2017 under `Tools --> Extensions and Updates --> Updates` solved the issue. Thank you!