# FabricElementNotFoundException: Application type and version not found

Tags: azure-service-fabric

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80071BDA
System.Fabric.Interop.NativeClient+IFabricApplicationManagementClient10.EndCreateApplication(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context)

FabricElementNotFoundException: Application type and version not found
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

Stack Query Cookies Headers
COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80071BDA
System.Fabric.Interop.NativeClient+IFabricApplicationManagementClient10.EndCreateApplication(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context)
System.Fabric.Interop.Utility+<>c__DisplayClass22_0.b__0(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context)
System.Fabric.Interop.AsyncCallOutAdapter2.Finish(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context, bool expectedCompletedSynchronously)

Show raw exception details
FabricElementNotFoundException: Application type and version not found
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Keefe.InmateStore.Administration.Controllers.AgencyController+d__5.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__27.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__25.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__22.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__20.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIIndexMiddleware+d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware+d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+d__7.MoveNext()

Comment: It's hard to understand your problem. Could you please provide more details on what you're trying to achieve when you get this error?

Comment: I have multiple services under one solution. In local cluster in debug x64 mode services are working fine no runtime issue. But when i deployed on server through tfs build and release under same environment configuration. I am getting this issue while calling service.

Comment: Also i have to set <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">  in csproj in some services in order to build on server. due to this error

The OutputPath property is not set for project 'X.Y.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Release'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project.

Answer (score 1):

You see this error, because Platform target should be x64 for Service Fabric projects.

Comment: Thanks! @Alex Riabov  Yes, i have targeted every SF project to x64. But still throwing build error. Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project. Configuration='Release' Platform='AnyCPU'.

Comment: @sumitgupta take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086795/the-outputpath-property-is-not-set-for-this-project actually, there are a lot of articles on this topic on SO