# Skipping dependency wixproject using msbuild command line

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, wix

I am building a wixproject using Visual studio solution on `Configuration= Release,Platform=x64` by unchecking `x86 platform` to skip some dependency wix projects.
 Is there a way to do the same using **MSBuild** command line?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with 'unchecking x86 platform? If you're building x64 as you say you're doing, no x86 stuff should be considered. Are you just looking to pass properties on the commandline to build for x64, like `msbuild myproject /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'?

Comment: unchecking x86 platform means - In Visual studio solution, there is an option to skip the platform x86 build by using VS configuration manager.

Comment: Whatever changes made in Configuration manager are saved in the solution file, so also get applied for commandline builds. In other words; you shouldn't do anything special.

Answer (score 0):

> Skipping dependency wixproject using msbuild command line

Just like stijn said, you can specify the property in the command line when you build the project/solution file.

As we know, the property `Platform=` project-level property, which we could set or override the specified project-level properties by `-property:name=value`. Name is the property name and value is the property value.

Check the document [MSBuild command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2017) for some more details.

[image]

So, to resolve this issue, you just need pass the property `Platform=x64` in the command line, like:

```
MSBuild YourProjectPath.wixproj /property:Configuration=Release /property:Platform=x64
```

or use shorter form:

```
MSBuild YourProjectPath.wixproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried below command 
msbuild a.wixproj /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=X64. 
a.wixproj has some dependency wixproj not supporting x64 platform.So how can we skip those wixproject while building a.wixproj with platform x64?

Comment: @NeethuHaridas, You can exclude projects at the solution level for a specific build configuration by using the Configuration Manager Dialog in Visual Studio:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778916/how-to-exclude-project-from-build-in-msbuild

Comment: instead of visual studio configuration manager , Is there any way to exclude project through msbuild command line?

Comment: @NeethuHaridas, Yes, there is no directly way to do this via command line. And all the settings in the visual studio configuration manager are saved in the project/solution file, if you have set this in the visual studio configuration manager, you do not specify it on the command line.

Comment: I am not using visual studio solution for build, I am calling wix project directly from msbuild  command line.

Comment: @NeethuHaridas, Got it, so what is your problem now? Exclude project through msbuild command line? If yes, this issue is not the same problem as you post in this thread, you should open a new thread with the new problem. One question one thread is recommended.

Comment: @NeethuHaridas, But I still don't know what your current problem is? Is the problem solved in the post? If not, then the question is now? If it's solved, then you have a new problem, as I said, close this one and open a new post.

Comment: My problem is not solved yet. I want to build wixproject directly through command line without using visual studio.

Comment: @NeethuHaridas, I know it, we have been discussing it all the time. So your problem is build wixproject directly through command line **Exclude** one project? Am I right? Or you just build the project  through command line? The command line is not use MSBuild command line `MSBuild YourProjectPath.wixproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64`?

Comment: @NeethuHaridas, Not working? What is the result? Any error message? You really should share the question, what have your tried and the result. Or I have to ask again and again.

Comment: Some of the dependency wixproject are failing with below error C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\wix2010.targets(508,7): error : The OutputPath property is not set for this project.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid Configuration/Platform combination.  Configuration='Release'  Platform='x64'

Comment: Check this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086795/the-outputpath-property-is-not-set-for-this-project/25973557#25973557