# How to target .Net Core from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, mono, cross-platform

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33028966/how-to-target-mono-framework-from-vs2015) suggests to target .Net Core.

I've installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and Mono Runtime. The list of target frameworks in visual studio looks this way (No .net core):

What should I do next?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem. 
My mistake was that I chose the template for 
Windows -> Console Application instead of 
Web -> Console Application 
when I created the new project. From your screenshot it looks like you did the same.

Depends on what you need. In my case I found that in the latest update for VS 2015 there's the option of Class Library (Portable) more suitable.

A useful add-on to VS 2013 and 2015 is .NET Portability Analyzer to check your code:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1177943e-cfb7-4822-a8a6-e56c7905292b?SRC=VSIDE