# Is it possible to debug Mono code in Windows?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, mono

A friend is developing a Mono app that will run on Linux on an Orange Pi. It is a non-gui console app. It has some Orange Pi specific things such as reading the GPIO pins, but other than that, the rest is basic reading/writing to a MySQL database and posting data to a Web API.

He sent me the code (written in Visual Studio), and asked me if I can help him with it. The problem is that I don't have an Orange Pi. I do have a Windows 10 PC with Visual Studio 2017 Professional. He told me that I can run this code in Visual Studio targeting .Net 4.5 and it will run (except for the GPIO bits). And indeed it does execute. But it's executing against the .Net Framework and for a more accurate test, I'd like it to execute against Mono. I see that it is possible to install Mono on Windows. But is it possible to get Visual Studio to target Mono? Or should I use another IDE other than VS?

Sorry, I'm brand new to Mono...

Comment: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/live-share/ Can you two do a Live Share session instead?

Comment: Install : https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/windows/ VS : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802605/using-visual-studio-for-developing-mono-applications or MonoDevelop IDE via source : https://www.monodevelop.com/download/#fndtn-download-win